# Fatal error: Call to undefined method

Tags: php

I am having this error

Fatal error: Call to undefined method RecursiveArrayIterator::fetch_array()  on line 128

```
$hierachy = new hierachy;
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new recursiveArrayIterator($hierachy->getSamelevelNode($name1)));
    try {
        while($row = $iterator->fetch_array()) {  //line where error is coming from 128
      if(!isset($targ)) {
       $targ = $row['left_node']+1; 
      }
      if($row['left_node'] == $targ) { 
        echo $row['name'];
        $targ = $row['right_node']+1; 
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your code also has mismatched braces here.  You have four `{` and only three `}`.

Comment: @Bacon Bits: obviously he did not paste `catch` part with "lost" `}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no such method: http://ru.php.net/RecursiveArrayIterator

Comment: I think there some kind of typo in between the function and the instatiation of the class and method.

Comment: @thephpdeveloper: my answer was good enough without your corrections

Comment: after I have correct the RecursiveArrayiterator I am having this

Comment: @fello: if you had working code, why did you change it to become wrong?

Comment: this is the function and the instantiation above                                                              public function getSamelevelNode(){
$stmt = conn::getInstance()->prepare("SELECT *
FROM categories
WHERE left_node = right_node");
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

Comment: @fello: `RecursiveIteratorIterator` class has no `fetch_array` method. This is what you've done wrong.

Comment: I have changed it becuase it was not giving me the restuls I want it

Comment: @fello: and now your code doesn't even work :-))) Why don't you ask a proper question with comprehensive description of what you have and what you want? Too bored to guess anymore.

Comment: @zerks now I have called the object $hiercachy with the method I wnat to retrieve. but this time there is not error displaying but there is not data either why is not displaying not data.                                      $hierachy->getSamelevelNode($name1))

Comment: Someone gave this while loop but I am not sure about somethings like the $targ variable I am not sure weather he meant the $name1 which is the variable I am using containing the value to be excuted.

Comment: @fello: developers **write** their own code, not copy-paste parts don't even realize what they do. Remove those lines and write **your** code from scratch.